# Not able to use multiple placeholders in Eloquent/Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using this as my query:

```php
$fields = DB::select('select * from ? where form_master_id=?',
[$field->table_name,$field->form_master_id]);
```

This gives me the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? where form_master_id=?' at line 1 (SQL:
> select * from articles where form_master_id=101)

but when I check the query: `select * from articles where form_master_id=101`, it works perfectly for me in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Are you sure you can use a placeholder for the table name? You might need to add <?=$field->table_name?> into the query for the table name and use the placeholder for just the where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking about Eloquent or Query Builder solution, but discussing only raw queries.

Query Builder solution is very simple:

```
DB::table($someTable)->where('form_master_id', $formMasterId)->get();
```

Eloquent solution:

```
$model = 'App\\' . $someModel;
$model::where('form_master_id', $formMasterId)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs, because you can't parameterise the table name. The name of the table needs to be static, which is why your second query works.

Generally speaking, if you've ended up needing to parameterise the name of the table *(which implies you are getting from some input)*, the logic behind your application is most likely wrong.

So, to make your code work, keep your parameters after `WHERE`:

```
$fields = DB::select(
   'select * from {$field -> table_name} where form_master_id=?',
   [$field -> form_master_id]
);
```

Comment: So is there anyway I could make the table name dynamic?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Generally speaking, if you've ended up needing to parameterise the name of the table _(which implies you are getting from some input)_ , there is a flaw in your logic.

Comment: I dont agree, I am trying to make my application table-driven, that is not a flaw in logic.

Comment: What you can and can't bind isn't a Laravel restriction or a PHP language restriction, it's an SQL restriction. Bind variables are placeholders for actual values in SQL statements.... note that's for __values__, not for column names, table names, etc

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: I wasn't talking about `Laravel` @MarkBaker; I was taking about `SQL`.

Answer (score 0):

I used a raw query to use my table name dynamically:

`$fields = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from $field->table_name
 where form_master_id=$field->form_master_id"));`